# windowssoftinputmode=Adjustpan is Not working properly when textalignment property center or center_horizantal

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, text-alignment, adjustpan

Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" has been specified in the AndroidManifest.xml, but it works only the first time.

second time the software keyboard is shown on the screen, it entirely hides my EditText.

**Image Description use the hyperlink for see the images.** First time EditText woks Properly
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49asH.jpg) hide and reopen the Keyboard Second time problem is occured.[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37k7j.jpg)

**Note:**

1.AdjustResize instaed of AdjustPan is work but I need adjustPan because AdjustResize the image was resized.

2.I'm also tried with create Own Edittext(Custom Edittext) with PreIme that also not working for me.

3.If remove text Alignment center works proper.But I need Text Alignment Center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.example.raj.testapp.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:alpha=".3"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:id="@+id/register_email"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:alpha=".3"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:hint="First name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/regiter_firstname"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:alpha=".3"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:hint="Lastname"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/regiter_lastname"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:alpha=".3"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/regiter_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:alpha=".3"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:id="@+id/register_confirm"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:id="@+id/register_next"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:background="@color/yellow"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
```

Comment: your next button hiding confirm password editText right

Comment: @AnilDS, Are you say Next button hiding the editext

Comment: Yes just give padding to your scrollview ex: 50sp and check

Comment: second time click the edittext the edittext was hidden

Comment: which edittext is hiding

Comment: add this line to your relative layout     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: confirm password editext is hide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147226/discussion-between-anil-ds-and-raj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a Custom editText file[LockEditext.java]

```
package com.raj.app.utils;

//import statements

public class LockEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

public LockEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public LockEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public LockEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        clearFocus();
    }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

2.XML file Change the com.raj.app.utils.LockEditText (Your packagename of the file.LockEditText) 
     For Example Like this

```
    <com.raj.app.utils.LockEditText
                android:id="@+id/regiter_firstname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:alpha=".3"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:hint="@string/firstname"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

**instead of**

```
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:alpha=".3"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:hint="First name"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/regiter_firstname"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

all the editext like this.

3.Java File

```
 EditText Reg_firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regiter_firstname);
```

EditText replace with LockEditText

Works fine and the code for when click done same problem is arise So add the following code.

```
LockEditText reg_confirm=(LockEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_confirm);

 reg_confirm.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
                            Reg_confirm.clearFocus();
                            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

if you don't need  to like large code then Simply use adjustResize in Manifest